# Auto Formatting adding text on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

Working on a shared project and my coworker created a new branch with an updated npm package (`@mui/material` from `@material-ui/core`). When I pull his branch and run `npm install` everything installs and works correctly. But now if I make a change to a file and then save (format on save is turned on), all my imports get formatted with value before them ex: `import React from 'react'` becomes `import value React from 'react'`. Not sure what to make of this because updating MUI shouldn't have changed anything related to formatting. He does not experience this problem.

We utilize ESLint v2.2.2 and Prettier - Code formatter v9.1.0  extensions in VS Code.

.eslintrc.json

```
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2020": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "react-app"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 11,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  }
}
```

.prettierrc

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

local settings

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "git.suggestSmartCommit": false,
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always"
}
```

Comment: found a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue after updating some yarn package versions.

For me, simply quitting VS Code and launching it again solved the problem.

Comment: Sadly I've quit and launched again multiple times, turned extensions on and off, etc with no luck.